# the of in - "More of a world commonwealth?"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> "Business" was much more of a world commonwealth than the political
> organisations.

*- The New World Order by H.G. Wells*

The word "of" confuses me.
According to the Cambridge dictionary, the "of" has several meanings and I can not fit any of them into this sentence:

- possession
- made of or consisting of
- about, relating to

I have two versions of this sentence:

1. Business can unify the world better than political organisations (can be a better commonwealth)
2. Business is a world commonwealth rather than political organisation.

Comment: I don't know which version of Cambridge you're looking at but it's right there [online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of#google_vignette) "used after words or phrases expressing amount, number, or a particular unit". "more" expresses an amount. Most English prepositions have a lot of uses and you need a good dictionary (better than your current one) and probably a grammar book to understand all their uses.

Answer (score 1):

> "Business" was much more of a world commonwealth than the political organisations.

I would say the meaning of "made of or consisting of" applies here.
"Business" is made of more of what a world commonwealth consists of than the political organisations.

"Mike Tyson was much more of a figher than the person I just passed by."

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following sentence:

> Purchasing stocks in a volatile market is **more of a risk** than purchasing bonds.

We can paraphrase **more of a risk** as "riskier" or "characterized by a greater element of risk".

So we could say that **of** there expresses the notion of possessing or having a quality or attribute.

But however you might want to word the definition, it is always helpful to find [other examples of the construction](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22more%20of%20a%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=571285583&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AM9HkKmnLe1WQqj-uBkjL1tlc3axflSSHA:1696592645034&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjX6r2PrOGBAxUNjYkEHTyTBhAQ0pQJKAV6BAgDEAg&biw=1246&bih=668&dpr=1) so that a definition will form in your own mind.